# How to use CloudFormation template from S3

Tags: aws-cdk

There is a section in documentation [Use an Existing AWS CloudFormation Template](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/use_cfn_template.html). It uses sync function from file system (`fs.readFileSync`). I am using CloudFormation template from S3 [EKS Public and private subnets](https://amazon-eks.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/cloudformation/2019-09-17/amazon-eks-vpc-private-subnets.yaml). According to my understanding AWS CDK is sync and I cannot use request library to fetch existing template.
There is an option to download yaml file to local file system.

I would like to use template directly from S3, if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, just use the aws-sdk to get the s3 contents from the bucket it's in.

```
async getCfnIncludeFromS3(): Promise<cdk.CfnInclude> {
  const s3 = new aws.S3();
  const template = await s3.getObject({Bucket: "MyBucket", Key: "My/Key/To/Template.json"}).promise();

  return new cdk.CfnInclude(this, "ExistingInfrastructure", {
    template: JSON.parse(template.Body).toString()
  });
}
```